# XSL Element Match

Tags: xml, xslt

I am very new to XSL and am trying to get to these elements out of my XML.

XSL 1 (creditreport.xsl)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cr="com/truelink/ds/sch/report/truelink/v3" xmlns:d1p1="com/truelink/ds/sch/report/truelink/v3" >
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="IS_SAMPLE" select="'false'"/>
    <xsl:param name="IS_PRINT_VIEW" select="'false'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="FILE_ID" select="110347814"/>
    <xsl:param name="TODAY_DATE" select="'May 23, 2009'"/>
    <xsl:param name="AVAILABLE_DATE" select="'Apr 23, 2009'"/>
    <xsl:include href="crBodyNew.xsl"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSL 2 (crBodyNew.xsl)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:d1p1="com/truelink/ds/sch/report/truelink/v3">

<xsl:template match="/" >

<!-- 3B VantageScoreV6-->
<html>
<head>
<link href="/report3B/stylesheets/base.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px">



<table id="reportTop" border="0" class="tableBorder" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="900">
<tr class="crTableHeader">
    <td width="25%">&#160;</td>
    <td class="tranunionHeaderColum" width="25%">TransUnion&#174;</td>
    <td class="experianHeaderColum" width="25%">Experian&#174;</td>
    <td class="equifaxHeaderColum" width="25%">Equifax&#174;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b class="crTradelineGroupHeader" id="vscore" align="left">VantageScore&#174; </b></td>
        <td>    
        [TUCVantageScoreV6 - riskScore Value Here]
        </td>
        <td>    
        [EXPVantageScoreV6 - riskScore Value Here]
        </td>
        <td>    
        [EQFVantageScoreV6 - riskScore Value Here]
        </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>





<table id="reportTop" border="0" class="tableBorder" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="900">
<tr class="crTableHeader">
    <td width="25%">&#160;</td>
    <td class="tranunionHeaderColum" width="25%">TransUnion&#174;</td>
    <td class="experianHeaderColum" width="25%">Experian&#174;</td>
    <td class="equifaxHeaderColum" width="25%">Equifax&#174;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b class="crTradelineGroupHeader" id="vscore" align="left">VantageScore&#174; </b></td>
        <td>    
        [TUCVantageScoreV6 - riskScore Value Here]
        </td>
        <td>    
        [EXPVantageScoreV6 - riskScore Value Here]
        </td>
        <td>    
        [EQFVantageScoreV6 - riskScore Value Here]
        </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

XML Snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="creditReport.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
<BundleComponents>
  <BundleComponent>
    <Type>TUCReportV6</Type>
  </BundleComponent>
  <BundleComponent>
    <Type>EQFReportV6</Type>
  </BundleComponent>
  <BundleComponent>
    <Type>EXPReportV6</Type>
  </BundleComponent>
  <BundleComponent>
    <Type>TUCVantageScoreV6</Type>
    <CreditScoreType xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" riskScore="638" scoreName="VantageScore3" populationRank="39">
      <CreditScoreFactor bureauCode="23" FactorType="Negative" xmlns="com/truelink/ds/sch/report/truelink/v3">
        <Factor abbreviation="" description="" symbol="23" rank="100000"/>
        <FactorText>explain: The VantageScore credit score model relies on information in your credit files at the three national credit reporting companies (Equifax, Experian and TransUnion) to generate your score. Your credit file does not have enough credit behavior information about your loans. A mix of different types of open and active credit accounts can have a positive impact on your credit score.</FactorText>
        <FactorText>factor: Lack of sufficient relevant account information</FactorText>
        <FactorText>cando: Maintaining open and active credit accounts in good standing can help improve your credit score.</FactorText>
      </CreditScoreFactor>
    </CreditScoreType>
  </BundleComponent>
  <BundleComponent>
    <Type>EQFVantageScoreV6</Type>
    <CreditScoreType xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" riskScore="586" scoreName="VantageScore3" populationRank="30">
      <CreditScoreFactor bureauCode="23" FactorType="Negative" xmlns="com/truelink/ds/sch/report/truelink/v3">
        <Factor abbreviation="" description="" symbol="23" rank="100000"/>
        <FactorText>Lack of sufficient relevant account information</FactorText>
      </CreditScoreFactor>
    </CreditScoreType>
  </BundleComponent>
  <BundleComponent>
    <Type>EXPVantageScoreV6</Type>
    <CreditScoreType xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" riskScore="628" scoreName="VantageScore3" populationRank="37">
      <CreditScoreFactor bureauCode="12" FactorType="Negative" xmlns="com/truelink/ds/sch/report/truelink/v3">
        <Factor abbreviation="" description="" symbol="12" rank="100000"/>
        <FactorText>The date that you opened your oldest account is too recent</FactorText>
      </CreditScoreFactor>
    </CreditScoreType>
  </BundleComponent>
</BundleComponents>
```

These are the components. Im sure this very easy for someone that is versed in XSL / XSLT. Im looking to get the fields out of the XML that you see in the brackets of crBodyNew.xsl

Please help.

Thanks,
Kenny

Comment: Show us what you've tried with a [mcve]. And include code here and not with links - links can vanish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression you want is this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="BundleComponents/BundleComponent[Type='TUCVantageScoreV6']/CreditScoreType/@riskScore" />
```

And similarly for the other two types.

Alternatively, define a key like so...

```
<xsl:key name="bundles" match="BundleComponent" use="Type" />
```

Then, you can simplify the `xsl:value-of` statement to this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('bundles', 'TUCVantageScoreV6')/CreditScoreType/@riskScore" />
```